# Como executar o código de uma classe no Android Studio quando não se tem um Activity?

Tags: android, classes, kotlin, prompt

Estou tentando aprender Kotlin, mas quero testar certos algoritmos e não consigo executar uma classe porque o Android Studio não encontra a Main Default. Será que não tem uma forma de executar uma classe no próprio prompt do Android Studio?
Essa IDE por acaso, só executa quando é pra rodar no emulador?

Comment: O Android Studio só compila se estiver com o emulador ligado ou com o celular plugado no PC. Pra aprender kotlin, a melhor ferramenta é o Intellij. Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize esse site oficial do Kotlin, lá existe a plataforma e tem a ferramenta para você executar somente o código e ver o resultado em tempo real sem a necessidade de instalar o Android Studio nesse momento, assim você foca em aprender a programar linguagem.

No site existem muitos exercícios para praticar e dominar a linguagem.

Vale a pena explorar o site e esse é o link:

https://play.kotlinlang.org/?_ga=2.75826076.802392123.1610591531-48417380.1594816894#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjAiLCJwbGF0Zm9ybSI6ImphdmEiLCJhcmdzIjoiIiwianNDb2RlIjoiIiwibm9uZU1hcmtlcnMiOnRydWUsInRoZW1lIjoiaWRlYSIsImNvZGUiOiIvKipcbiAqIFlvdSBjYW4gZWRpdCwgcnVuLCBhbmQgc2hhcmUgdGhpcyBjb2RlLiBcbiAqIHBsYXkua290bGlubGFuZy5vcmcgXG4gKi9cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihcIkhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCEhISBvb29vXCIpXG59In0=

Bons estudos.